# Trouble Installing a Package to PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I'm using PyCharm and want to mess around with a few features in scikit-learn.
I'm fairly certain I've set everything up correctly, and I've installed other packages, but I'm running into an error here.
Thus far I've been using the python Interpreter menu in PyCharm to download all my packages but it's been installing build dependencies for some time...
I'm on Python 3.10 and PyCharm Community 2021.2.3
Do I need to downgrade my Python version (i.e. scikit doesn't support 3.10)?

For reference, it's stuck here:
[image: download]

Comment: can you pip install it via the terminal (into the same venv?) ... i would hazard a guess that it needs a c compiler you are missing... there is theoretically a more helpful error message than what you have shown

Comment: Just for kicks, I'm going to try installing scikit-learn on pyenv with Python 3.10; will let you know how it goes. It seems to be taking a while for me now actually.

Comment: I confirmed it's likely the python version 3.10 that doesn't seem to be supported. My pip install from a terminal is still hanging in 3.10; for my system version 3.9 it just completed in a few seconds.

Comment: It is probably not hanging but compiling C code as there is no pre-compiled version for Python 3.10 available. Compiling from scratch is quite a slow process.